# Changing Fonts In Javascript's CanvasJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, canvasjs

I am using graphs from canvas.js. They are all built, but I cant figure out how to change the font size or font family in the output.

```
var ctx = $("#line");


        var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: chartdata
        });
    },
```

I am guessing it is added here, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can change font property like below;

```
var  chart =  new  CanvasJS.Chart("container",
{

 title:{
  fontSize: 30,
  fontColor: "red",
 },

});

chart.render();
```

for more customizations you can check this [link](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/)